# rx synchronize multiple event observables by time stamp

Tags: c#, time, system.reactive

I have several observables created from different events and use the sample method to create samples of equal time span. The problem is that they are created and started at different times and so I get equally spaced time series that are all shifted. I can't force the creation time, so therefore I would like to work with a reference time stamp to align all these observables.

So let's say the sample interval is 5 sec and the reference time stamp is `01-Jan-1969 00:00:00`

I would get the following times series:

```
19-Nov-2012 08:00:00
19-Nov-2012 08:00:05
19-Nov-2012 08:00:10
....
```

The question is of course how to do that in RX.

The goal is to have aligned time series form events for a plot.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show us what you are currently doing?

Comment: Does `Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))` work for you?

Comment: No this would not help since .multiple time.series started at different times would not be aligned.

Comment: That's what `Buffer` does, it groups (or aligns) observables that occur at different times. You have to specify an allowable window of time to bring them together. `Buffer` does that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    IObservable<long> Sequence1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    IObservable<long> Sequence2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    //1st subscription
    Sequence1.Timestamp().Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)).Subscribe(item1 =>
    Console.WriteLine("Buffer 1: {0} Value: {1}", item1[item1.Count[1].
    Timestamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), item1[item1.Count - 1].Value));
    //some delay
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    //2nd subscription
    Sequence2.Timestamp().Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)).Subscribe(item2 =>
    Console.WriteLine("Buffer 2: {0} Value: {1}", item2[item2.Count - 1].
    Timestamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), item2[item2.Count - 1].Value));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Sequence 1 and 2 are different data sources and I would like to align them so that for example the buffer closes at the same time stamp.